# How to make jQuery animation for body of html?

Tags: jquery

I am making a website and I'm trying to add three images to the web page and make them rotate with jQuery. I have read a lot of several threats about jQuery :not() function for excluding child elements from animation but can't get it do it  the right way. The problem is that I only need the 3 background images( wich are attached to ) to fade in and not all other elements too like menu, header or site content. Here is my code, hope someone can help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
 var imgArr = new Array() // relative paths of images
 imgArr[0]="images/1.jpg";
 imgArr[1]="images/2.jpg";
 imgArr[2]="images/3.jpg";


 var preloadArr = new Array();
 var i;

 /* preload images */
 for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
 preloadArr[i] = new Image();
 preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
 }

 var currImg = 1;
 var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 1000);

 /* image rotator */
 function changeImg(){
 $(".wrapper").not('dont know').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
 $(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') top center no-repeat');
 }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);

 }

 });

</script>
```

What I need is to animate only the body background to fade in and not the child elements of it
like menus, paragraphs, site content, etc.
Thanks for any suggestions.

The Html part:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="inline_element1">Here goes menu</div>
   <div class="inline_element2">Here goes site content</div>
</div>
```

In the CSS part:

```
.parent{

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I need to animate only the  and not all the elements inside too like and . Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that kind of animation (opacity of background image) supported in jQuery? Even if it is, your selector currently selects "all `html` elements which are not also a `body` element." That will simply return the `html` element. What exactly are you trying to select with `$('html').not('body')`?

Comment: I need to animate just the parent element and not its children for example: <div class="wrapper">Here goes 3 images</div><div class="menu">Menu here</div><div class="content">Site content here</div>. I need to fade in (animate) only the   class 'wrapper'. How can I achieve that? Cheers\

Comment: what 'parent element'? Can you provide the HTML you're working with and show us what elements you're targeting?

Answer (score 0):

If i undertsand, you need to animate and fadeI the background of the parent while not fading the content inside.  This is simply impossible and by that, i mean that if you remove a  (or fadeIn/fadeOut or whatever you do on it), you remove all of his children at the same time because its in the same container.  That's the way the DOM was created.  Knowing that, there are still way to "fake" the background image, like for instance a DIV inside the parent, in position absolute, top 0 and left 0 (parent must be relative), with height and width at 100% and z-index at -1 (make sure it is behind everything).  Than you can simply fadeIn/Out that perticular div.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class='fakeBackground'></div>
 <div class="inline_element1">Here goes menu</div>
 <div class="inline_element2">Here goes site content</div>
</div>

.parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   position: relative;

}   
.parent .fakeBackground {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

and then:

```
// you have to figure out yourself how to point the parent, or if it is all at the same 
// time, just go with $('.fakeBackground').fadeOut(1000, etc.)
$('.parent').children('.fakeBackground').fadeOut(1000,function() {
  // change background like you want
});
```